# Custom Tab not displaying on product page in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.3, product-detail-page

I need to show a custom tab after the Review tab on the product detail page. I am using Magento 2.4.3.
Below is my code
**[vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
<referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab" template="Cloudways_Mymodule::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
<arguments>
<argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

**[vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/templates/custom_tab.phtml**

```
<?php

echo "This is Custom tab in product detail page";

?>
```

Please help me to know what is wrong with the above code as the custom tab is not displaying.

Comment: Please check my answer. magento 2.4.3 there some changes, that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
        <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="test.tab"  template="Vendor_Extension::custom_tab.phtml" group="detailed_info">
           <arguments>
              <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
           </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
</page>
```

Confirm this point :

1. Your extension is register into magento and enable.

Comment: Yes I have checked it is there

Answer (score 0):

I did a similar thing using following steps :

Added catalog_product_view.xml in my custom theme

> app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/layout

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.ingredients" template="product/view/ingredients.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Ingredients</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Added ingredients.phtml in

> app/design/frontend/Anshu/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view

```
<?php 
$product = $block->getProduct();
echo $product->getData('ingredients');
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

vendor/magento/module-page-builder/view/frontend/page_layout/product-full-width.xml

Please check this file and comment ->"product.info.details"